# Decode this signal from outer space

Tags: mathematics, physics

A light signal is received from outer space at a frequency of 982.002MHz

Calculate the wavelength of the signal and identify a corresponding earth unit.

By using the exact value of the unit convert the frequency back into a speed to reveal a well known constant.

Comment: (some?) spoiler: https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?PHPSESSID=ui0k929sceqvjsu6snmjf8b3ju&topic=43914.msg2171273#msg2171273

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Happy π Day

From physics wavelength = speed/frequency and given the speed of light is 299792458 m/s. So that

> The wavelength is 0.305287... metres which is approximately one foot.

Flipping the equation to speed = wavelength * frequency we see

> That if we add a more exact expression for one foot in metres such as 0.3048 m we get 299.3142096 Mft/s.

My suspicion is that if I had used more accurate decimal places it would read

> 299.31415926... which would be very appropriate for today.

Comment: Congratulations, you've made the first step in decoding BLC1.